# How to deploy configuration files,jars and ear files in remote weblogic server using ant script

Tags: ant, weblogic12c

I want to deploy the jar files,configuration files and generated ear file on remote weblogic server using ant script.

I have created ant script that stop the weblogic server,delete old files(jar,config xml files,ear) copy the given source to destination,this script is work when source and destination both are having on same machine.

```
<project name="Svn" default="startserver">
<property name="bea.home" value="C:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home" />
<property name="weblogic.home" value="${bea.home}/wlserver" />
<property name="domain.home" value="${bea.home}/user_projects/domains" />
<property name="domain.name" value="NAPF_domain" />
<property name="host" value="10.254.5.191" />
<property name="port" value="7001" />
<property name="username" value="weblogic" />
<property name="password" value="weblogic" />
<property name="admin.server.name" value="AdminServer" />
<property name="libdeploy.dir" value="${domain.home}/${domain.name}/lib/" />
<property name="configdeploy.dir" value="${domain.home}/${domain.name}/pf-appl/config/" />
<property name="eardeploy.dir" value="${domain.home}/${domain.name}/servers/AdminServer/upload/" />
<property name="libsource.dir" value="napf-main/napf-build/release/target/Release/lib/" />
<property name="configsource.dir" value="napf-main/napf-build/release/target/Release/config/" />
<property name="earsource.dir" value="napf-main/napf-build/release/target/Release/dist/" />
<property name="napfscutitysource.dir" value="napf-main/napf-security-lib" />
<property name="sourceMonitorHome" location="NAPF_SERVER_SOURCE/SourceMonitor"/>

<path id="wls.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${weblogic.home}/server/lib">
        <include name="web*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>
<taskdef name="wlserver" classname="weblogic.ant.taskdefs.management.WLServer" classpathref="wls.classpath" />
<target name="start-server">
    <wlserver dir="${domain.home}/${domain.name}" host="${host}" port="${port}" domainname="${domain.name}" servername="${admin.server.name}" action="start" username="${username}" password="${password}" beahome="${bea.home}" weblogichome="${weblogic.home}" verbose="true" noexit="true" protocol="t3" classpath="${weblogic.home}/server/lib/weblogic.jar">
        <jvmarg value="-server" />
        <jvmarg value="-Xms256m" />
        <jvmarg value="-Xmx512m" />
        <jvmarg value="-XX:PermSize=128m" />
        <jvmarg value="-XX:MaxPermSize=256m" />
    </wlserver>
    <sleep seconds="2" />
</target>
<target name="stop-server">
    <wlserver dir="${domain.home}/${domain.name}" host="${host}" port="${port}" servername="${admin.server.name}" username="${username}" password="${password}" action="shutdown" beahome="${bea.home}" weblogichome="${weblogic.home}" forceshutdown="true" />
</target>
<target name="purge-deploy" description="Delete old deploy files.">
    <echo message="Deleting old deploy files..." />
    <delete includeEmptyDirs="true">
        <!-- Delete all jar files  -->
        <fileset dir="${libdeploy.dir}" includes="**/*" />
        <!-- Delete all config files  -->
        <fileset dir="${configdeploy.dir}" includes="**/*" />
    </delete>
</target>
<target name="copyToSecurityLib" description="Copy files to napf security folder.">
    <copy todir="${libdeploy.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${napfscutitysource.dir}">
            <include name="**" />
            <!-- ignore files/folders starting with svn -->
            <exclude name="**/.svn" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>
<target name="copyToDeploy" description="Copy files to deploy folder.">
    <copy todir="${libdeploy.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${libsource.dir}">
            <include name="**" />
            <!-- ignore files/folders starting with svn -->
            <exclude name="**/.svn" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="${configdeploy.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${configsource.dir}">
            <include name="**" />
            <!-- ignore files/folders starting with svn -->
            <exclude name="**/.svn" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="${eardeploy.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${earsource.dir}">
            <include name="**" />
            <!-- ignore files/folders starting with svn -->
            <exclude name="**/.svn" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>

<target name="purgeReport" description="Delete old report files.">
    <echo message="Deleting old report files..." />
    <delete includeEmptyDirs="true">
        <fileset dir="${sourceMonitorHome}" includes="**/*.csv,*.jpeg,*.smp" />
    </delete>
</target>

<target name="startSourceMonitor">
    <exec dir="${sourceMonitorHome}" executable="cmd" failonerror="true" spawn="false">
      <arg value="/c"/>
      <arg value="sourcemonitor.bat"/>
    </exec>

</target>

<target name="copyReportFiles" description="Copy files to napf source directory to slave workspace directory.">
    <delete includeEmptyDirs="true">
        <fileset dir="${sourceMonitorWorkSpace}"/>
    </delete>
    <mkdir dir="${sourceMonitorWorkSpace}"/>
     <sleep seconds="1" />
    <copy todir="${sourceMonitorWorkSpace}">
        <fileset dir="${sourceMonitorHome}">
            <include name="**/*.csv" />
             <include name="**/*.jpeg" />
            <exclude name="**/.svn" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try **wldeploy** Ant task.

First, add task definition.

```
<taskdef name="wldeploy" classname="weblogic.ant.taskdefs.management.WLDeploy">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="${weblogic.home}/server/lib/weblogic.jar"/>
    </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

Next, configure each action of wldeploy task, such as deploy, redeploy, or undeploy specifically.

Example,

```
<!-- The deployment name for the deployed application.
If you do not specify this attribute, WebLogic Server assigns a deployment name to the application, based on its archive file or exploded directory. -->
<property name="deploy.name" value="MyApp"/>
<!-- The archive file or exploded directory to deploy. -->
<property name="deploy.source" value="MyApp.ear"/>
<!-- The list of target servers to which the application is deployed.
The value of this attribute is a comma-separated list of the target servers, clusters, or virtual hosts.
If you do not specify a target list when deploying an application, the target defaults to the Administration Server instance. -->
<property name="deploy.targets" value="MyCluster"/>

<!-- Deploying Applications  -->
<target name="deploy">
<wldeploy action="deploy" 
          name="${deploy.name}"
          user="${username}"
          password="${password}"
          remote="true"
          adminurl="t3://${host}:${port}"
          source="${deploy.source}"
          targets="${deploy.targets}"/>
</target>

<!-- Redeploying Applications  -->
<target name="redeploy">
<wldeploy action="redeploy"
          name="${deploy.name}"
          user="${username}"
          password="${password}"
          remote="true"
          adminurl="t3://${host}:${port}"
          targets="${deploy.targets}"/>
</target>

<!-- Undeploying Applications  -->
<target name="undeploy">
<wldeploy action="undeploy"
          name="${deploy.name}"
          failonerror="false"
          user="${username}"
          password="${password}"
          remote="true"
          adminurl="t3://${host}:${port}" 
          targets="${deploy.targets}"/>
</target>
```

Please note that if we want to deploy the JAR or EAR to remote WebLogic server, we must explicitly set the **remote** attribute in wldeploy tag to true, since the default value is false.

More complete reference regarding the task can be found on https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e13706/wldeploy.htm

Comment: Thanks Aprian. I have tried the above wldeploy Ant task but i am getiing error "taskdef class weblogic.ant.taskdefs.management.WLDeploy cannot be found".I have set the classpath <path id="wls.classpath">
 <fileset dir="C:/weblogic_jar/">
  <include name="weblogic.jar" />
  <include name="wldeploy.jar" />
 </fileset>
 </path>

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, Sameek. Strange. WLDeploy class should exist in weblogic.jar actually. May I know which version of WebLogic are you using? Also, could you try to define the specific classpath for the wldeploy task? I've updated the taskdef sample.

Comment: I am using weblogic 12.2.1.

Comment: I am only setting weblogic.jar and wldeploy.jar files in classpath from my customer location.if i am loading jar from using following location C:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/ ,it execute the ant script.strange behaviour..do you have any idea?

Comment: used settings: <path id="wls.classpath">
    <fileset dir="C:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/">
            <include name="weblogic.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>
   <taskdef name="wldeploy" classname="weblogic.ant.taskdefs.management.WLDeploy" classpathref="wls.classpath"/>

Comment: It's difficult if we don't know whether the weblogic.jar in C:/weblogic_jar/ and C:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/ folder are identical or not. Most likely, the JAR file in the latter folder contains all classes required by WLDeploy (or even the WLDeploy class itself); therefore, you can execute the Ant script.

Answer (score 0):

The above task would work if you are just specifying the remote server file path. Essentially you would need two parameters one is remote and other being upload.
The same would work but i see an parameter is missing for the task if you are deploying from a remote server

```
<target name="deploy1">
<wldeploy action="deploy"
      upload="true"
      remote="true"
          name="${deploy.name.1}"
          source="${deploy.source.1}"
          user="${wls.username}"
          password="${wls.password}"
          verbose="true"
          adminurl="t3://${wls.hostname}:${wls.port}" targets="${deploy.target}" />
</target>
```